# Git doesn't sync files until committed, even if checked out in a different branch

Tags: git, branch

Okay, I have git 1.7.11.1 on Windows and I have a local test repository with 2 branches. One is master with index.php and help.php. I then create another branch called slave :)

I run from git `bash rm help.php` and it disappears from the folder, but I don't stage anything. I switch to checkout master branch and it is supposed to restore file help.php because it is not modified in the master branch, isn't it?

And it does not do it. When I go back to the slave branch and commit and then switch to checkout master then help.php appears. Is that the way it is supposed to to work? Why?

Comment: @nischayn22 just vote to close as off topic.  This allows you to tell the system to move it to StackOverflow.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: A user needs at least 3000 reputation to cast close votes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the version of `help.php` in `master` and `slave` is the same version otherwise git wouldn't have let you change branches.

Unstaged and staged changes aren't committed to any branch yet so, if there are no conflicts, git will let you carry these changes between branches. If you had committed the removal to `slave` then the file would have come back when you switched `master`.

As it is, you can "undo" the removal (while on either branch) with:

```
git checkout -- help.php
```

This will checkout the index version of `help.php` back into your working tree.

If you had staged but not committed the removal you would have to check the `HEAD` version out with:

```
git checkout HEAD -- help.php
```